# How is independence between two family of random variables defined?

Tags: probability-theory

Given a family of random variables are jointly independent, how is independence between two family of random variables defined? An example is from [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/). Thanks!

> Exercise 18 (Creation of new, independent random variables) Let $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of random variables (not necessarily independent or finite), and let $(\mu_\beta)_{\beta \in B}$ be a collection (not necessarily finite) of probability measures $\mu_\beta$ on measurable spaces $R_\beta$. Then, after extending the sample space if necessary, one can find a family $(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in B}$ of independent random variables, such that each ${Y_\beta}$ has distribution ${\mu_\beta}$, and the two families $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ and $(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in B}$ are independent of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the two sigma-fields
$$
\sigma\left(\{X_\alpha\mid \alpha\in A\}\right)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\{X^{-1}_\alpha(B)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}\right)\qquad (1)
$$
and
$$
\sigma\left(\{Y_\beta\mid \beta \in B\}\right)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{\beta\in B}\{Y^{-1}_\beta(B)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}\right)\qquad (2)
$$
are independent. Two sigma-fields $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are independent whenever 
$$
P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B),\quad A\in\mathcal{A},\;B\in\mathcal{B}.
$$

In fact $\sigma\left(\{X_\alpha\mid \alpha\in A\}\right)$ is the sigma-field generated by the system 
$$
\left\{\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(B_i)\}\;\bigg|\; \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in A\text{ are distinct},\; B_1,\ldots,B_n\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right\},\qquad (*)
$$
which obviously is stable under intersection. Let us use the following result:

> If $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are systems of sets that are stable under finitely many intersections, then
>   $$
> \mathcal{G} \text{ and }\mathcal{F} \text{ are independent} \iff \sigma(\mathcal{G})\text{ and }\sigma(\mathcal{F}) \text{ are independent}.
> $$

It shows that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are independent if and only if $(*)$ and $(**)$ are independent, where $(**)$ is the analogue of $(*)$ for the family $(Y_\beta)_{\beta\in B}$.

But this is just saying that
$$
\begin{align}
P\big(&(X_{\alpha_1},\ldots,X_{\alpha_n})^{-1}(B_1)\cap (Y_{\beta_1},\ldots,Y_{\beta_k})^{-1}(B_2)\big)\\
&=P\big((X_{\alpha_1},\ldots,X_{\alpha_n})^{-1}(B_1)\big)\cdot P\big((Y_{\beta_1},\ldots,Y_{\beta_k})^{-1}(B_2)\big)
\end{align}
$$
for every choice $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in A$, $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k\in B$, $B_1\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $B_2\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ and $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you! Does "If G and F are systems of sets that are stable under intersection" mean finitely many intersections (i.e. pi system) or arbitrarily many intersections?

Comment: @Ethan: You're welcome, and it means finitely many.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite families of $\sigma$-algebras are said to be independent if all finite subfamilies are independent.  So for two families of random variables to be independent, I believe it is sufficient (and it is certainly necessary) that
$$
E[f(X_1,...,X_n)g(Y_1,...,Y_m)]=E[f(X_1,...,X_n)]\cdot E[g(Y_1,...,Y_m)]
$$
for any measurable functions $f$ and $g$ and for any finite sequences of variables $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$ drawn from the first and second families.